# Nginx doesn't create cache files (using uwsgi+php)

Tags: php, caching, nginx, uwsgi

I use nginx as a web server and I want to cache everything for my homepage "/". It's a PHP application and I'm using uWSGI with the PHP plugin.

This is in my nginx vhost configuration file:

```
proxy_cache_path  /var/lib/nginx/ levels=1   keys_zone=cache:10m
                  max_size=1000m inactive=600m;
proxy_temp_path   /tmp;
```

and:

`

```
location = / {
     proxy_cache cache;
     proxy_cache_key $host$uri;
     proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie Cache-Control Expires;
     proxy_cache_valid      200  1d;

     include uwsgi_params;
     uwsgi_modifier1 14;
     uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:4001;
     try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
  }
```

I'm not getting anything in /var/lib/nginx. The user used for nginx is www-data, and it is the owner of everything inside /var/lib/nginx/

What I'm a missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the nginx uwsgi module has its caching options, just change proxy_ to uwsgi_ like uwsgi_cache instead of proxy_cache

Comment: thanks for the comment, but I'd like to know if it is possible to use nginx for this.

Comment: uwsgi_cache is a nginx option :)